# What would be a more optimal way of filtering a list into sub-lists

Tags: c#, performance

In the start of one of my methods I have a section of code that needs to get three sub-lists of grouped dictionaries from a list of grouped dictionaries. This is a big list and I'm optimizing it a little by only looking at a smaller sub-list generated from a communal attribute.

Is there a faster a way to generate these three lists.

Code

```
 private List<List<CellData>> FormatOfficeData(List<Dictionary<References.ColHeaders, CellData>> dataOffice)
    {
        List<Dictionary<References.ColHeaders, CellData>> dataDownTown = new List<Dictionary<References.ColHeaders, CellData>>();
        List<Dictionary<References.ColHeaders, CellData>> dataSuburban = new List<Dictionary<References.ColHeaders, CellData>>();
        List<Dictionary<References.ColHeaders, CellData>> dataTotal = new List<Dictionary<References.ColHeaders, CellData>>();

        dataOffice = dataOffice.Where(x => x[References.ColHeaders.AssetClass].val == "All Classes" && (
        x[References.ColHeaders.Submarket].val == "Downtown" ||
        x[References.ColHeaders.Submarket].val == "Suburban" ||
        x[References.ColHeaders.Submarket].val == "Total")).ToList();
        dataDownTown = dataOffice.Where(x => x[References.ColHeaders.Submarket].val == "Downtown").ToList();
        dataSuburban = dataOffice.Where(x => x[References.ColHeaders.Submarket].val == "Suburban").ToList();
        dataTotal = dataOffice.Where(x => x[References.ColHeaders.Submarket].val == "Total").ToList();

... Code continues
```

Comment: you should provide a working code. non-working codes will be ignored.

Comment: The code does work. I can just simply return null and the everything works. Or do you mean I should post all code that implement this function? I can recreate dummy data and pass it in if need be.

Comment: yes, minimal code is required and sample data is appreciated as well as an example of how the data needs to be organized.

Comment: @Mandelbrotter you should post the full code (the method code) plus any implemented functions, classes, interfaces ..etc. that are used in the code. providing this is required.